# Sharepoint Migration from one domain to another

Tags: migration, stsadm

I have an active sharepoint farm already built and I am wanting to create an exact mirror copy of the sites and all its contents into a different domain for develpoment and testing. The share point site is live and can not be brougt down I have tried using sharepoint designer to migrate the sites but this comes up with a multitude of errors. I have also looked at stsadm.exe but I am not sure what commands i need and can I use this on a live site.

I have also tried the inbuild backup restore tool within sarepoint but this sill comes back with an error. I am using sharpoint office 2007 with sharepoing central admin 3.0.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a "live" backup of the content database in SQL level (do not try to move configuration database). This can be don by SQL management studio. 
Then copy it to the other domain, restore SQL database and attach it to sharepoint.

Do not forget to `stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin <DOMAIN\name> -newlogin <DOMAIN\name> [-ignoresidhistory]` to migrate the users.

Comment: Is there a script that has been created to automate this.

Comment: And will this move the site contents

Comment: Yes, moving the "wss_content_something" database moves all the site contents in there. Since I am a developer and have never ever created a SQL backup in my life, I do not know how to script a SQL backup. But I know my SQL administrators do it on a daily basis.